# Show status bar notification in certain time

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I want to show the user notifications everyday in the same time. For now I only have this code:

My TimeAlarm.class that shows the notifications:

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    NotificationManager nm;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        nm = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        CharSequence from = "Nithin";
        CharSequence message = "Crazy About Android...";
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(), 0);
        Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                "Crazy About Android...", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
        notif.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.test);
//      r.play();
        nm.notify(1, notif);
    }
}
```

And initialization of the notifications to show every 5 seconds:

```
public void setRepeatingAlarm() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                (5 * 1000), pendingIntent);
    }
```

Now my question is how should I modify this code to set the notification to repeat every day in certain time. Example every day in 14:36 o'clock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy-but-inexact way is to change `System.currentTimeMillis()` to a calculation of 14:36 tomorrow, probably using a `Calendar` object:

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 36);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

if (cal.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
  cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
}
```

I say "easy-but-inexact" because Android 4.4 has changed the behavior of `setRepeating()` to be inexact, once your `android:targetSdkVersion` is 19 or higher. If you need exact alarms, you will need to use `setExact()` and do your own "repeating" (by calling `setExact()` again when the alarm goes off). You would still use the same `Calendar` sort of calculation, just on every `setExact()` call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you tell me how can I disable the repeating of the alarm?

Comment: @DarkoPetkovski: Call `cancel()` on `AlarmManager`.

Comment: Thanks for the perfect but simple answer.